FrozenError in colored2 gem while running pod install in CocoaPods 1.16.2
I'm encountering a FrozenError when trying to run pod install with CocoaPods 1.16.2. The error occurs during the execution of the colored2 gem, specifically in the ascii_decorator.rb file. The error message is as follows:
/Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/colored2-3.1.2/lib/colored2/ascii_decorator.rb:67:in `decorate': can't modify frozen String: "" (FrozenError)
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/colored2-3.1.2/lib/colored2.rb:26:in `surround_with_color'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/colored2-3.1.2/lib/colored2.rb:62:in `block (3 levels) in included'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:14:in `report'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
from /Users/local/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
from /Users/local/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
from /Users/local/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/bin/pod:25:in `load'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
/Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/colored2-3.1.2/lib/colored2/ascii_decorator.rb:67:in `decorate': can't modify frozen String: "" (FrozenError)
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/colored2-3.1.2/lib/colored2.rb:26:in `surround_with_color'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/colored2-3.1.2/lib/colored2.rb:51:in `block (3 levels) in included'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:131:in `validate'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/abstract_external_source.rb:191:in `block in validate_podspec'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:41:in `with_changes'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/abstract_external_source.rb:190:in `validate_podspec'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/abstract_external_source.rb:178:in `store_podspec'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:17:in `block in fetch'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:11:in `fetch'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:997:in `fetch_external_source'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:976:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_external_sources'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:975:in `each'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:975:in `block in fetch_external_sources'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:974:in `fetch_external_sources'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:118:in `analyze'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
from /Users/local/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.16.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/bin/pod:25:in `load'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
from /Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'

Steps to reproduce:
I am using Ruby 3.2.0 and CocoaPods 1.16.2.
I run the command pod install on my project.
The error happens during the installation process.
What I've tried:
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the colored2 gem.
I attempted updating CocoaPods to the latest version, but the issue persists.
I tried clearing the CocoaPods cache (pod cache clean --all), but that didn’t help.
System Information:
Ruby version: 3.2.0 (installed via RVM)
CocoaPods version: 1.16.2
colored2 gem version: 3.1.2
macOS version: 14.6.1 (23G93)
Can anyone help me understand why this error occurs, and how I can resolve it?
Thank you!

Somehow frozen string literals appears to be turned on. I could understand if this was ruby 3.4 where that is the default but it is not. I cannot determine why this is occurring in your particular case. Maybe check your RUBYOPT environment variable to ensure it does not include the --enable=frozen-string-literal directive?
